# Replace method with method of instance of different class

Tags: python, class, methods

I just tried to make a system with some classes with similar parent class, which dynamically assigns their method between them, It looks like one function "transform(from, to)", which doing smth like from.foo = to.foo

So, you see, that my problem is difficult with Python, so I'm asking for help

My first try was

```py
def transform(a, b):
    a.foo = b.foo


class A:
    def foo(self):
        pass


class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("bar")
        transform(self, C())


class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")
        transform(self, B())

b = C()
b.foo()
b.foo()
b.foo()
b.foo()
```

I want to get from it smth like

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

But I get

```
foo
bar
bar
bar
```

The funniest moment of all is that first conversion working, but next.

---

My next try was

```py
class A:
    def foo(self):
        pass

    def transform(self, to):
        self.foo = to.foo


class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("bar")
        self.transform(C())


class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")
        self.transform(B())

b = C()
b.foo()
b.foo()
b.foo()
b.foo()
```

and I got the same result. Do you have any idea how to manage this conversion?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, it first runs `a.foo = b.foo`, where `a` was the object created at `b = C()`, and b was the object created at `B()`. Then when `a.foo()` is next run, it runs B's `foo(self)` where `self` is that `B()` object.  There, it runs `transform(self, C())` where `self` is still the object created with `B()`, *not* the object at `b`. Basically, `b` is only modified once then never modified again.

Instead, you should get the unbound function object of `foo` with `b.foo.__func__` before assigning it to the other one, or the `self` in `foo` will refer to the object `B()` instead of `b`. Then, you can bind it back to the destination object with `types.MethodType`:

```
from types import MethodType

def transform(a, b):
    a.foo = MethodType(b.foo.__func__, a)

class A:
    def foo(self):
        pass


class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("bar")
        transform(self, C())


class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")
        transform(self, B())

b = C()
b.foo()
b.foo()
b.foo()
b.foo()
```

> ```
> foo
> bar
> foo
> bar
> ```

---

Your 2nd attempt is also fixed by doing the same thing:

```
from types import MethodType

class A:
    def foo(self):
        pass

    def transform(self, to):
        self.foo = MethodType(to.foo.__func__, self)


class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("bar")
        self.transform(C())


class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")
        self.transform(B())

b = C()
b.foo()
b.foo()
b.foo()
b.foo()
```

> ```
> foo
> bar
> foo
> bar
> ```

Comment: So he was changing the `self` object between calls this is why it wasn't working?

Comment: @geckos yes, in asker's original code, the first time it ran `a.foo = b.foo`, where `a` was the object created at `b = C()`, and b was the object created at `B()`--then when `a.foo()` was next run, it would run B's `foo(self)` where `self` was that `B()` object.  There, it would run `transform(self, C())` where `self` was the object created by `B()`. Basically, `b` was only modified once then never modified again.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!